# Python get requests for an API URL returns 422 error but on browser no problems. Potential service worker problem?

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, python-requests, service-worker

I have noticed that for some websites' API Urls, the return on the browser is via a service worker which has caused problems in scraping those APIs.

**For consider the following:**

https://www.sephora.co.id/api/v2.3/products?filter[category]=makeup/face/bronzer&page[size]=30&page[number]=1&sort=sales&include=variants,brand

The data appears when the url is pasted into a browser **However** it gives me a 422 error when I try to automate the collection of that data in Python with the following code:

```
import requests

#API url
url = 'https://www.sephora.co.id/api/v2.3/products?filter[category]=makeup/face/bronzer&page[size]=30&page[number]=1&sort=sales&include=variants,brand'

#The response is always 422
response = requests.get(url)
```

I have noticed that when calling the API url on the browser returns a response via a service worker. Therefore my questions is there a way around to get a 200 response via the python requests library?

Comment: Do you need to pass any additional info in the headers for example?

Comment: No. I even tried putting in a user-agent header and it still doesn't work. 

If you try using the url sample above you will see that the request via the browser goes through with just user agent and returns json data but via python's requests module, there is nothing returned but a 422 error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server appears to require the `Accept-Language` header.
The code below now returns 200.

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.sephora.co.id/api/v2.3/products?filter[category]=makeup/face/bronzer&page[size]=30&page[number]=1&sort=sales&include=variants,brand'

headers = {'Accept-Language': 'en-gb'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

(Ascertained by checking a successful request via a browser, adding in all headers AS IS to the python request and then removing one by one.)

[image: Headers from Safari webdev tools]